# Can you stack multiple IF statements in ASP?? Mine isn't working

Tags: asp.net

I am in charge of the eCommerce site for the company I am working for. I'm fairly new to any programming and have mostly learned from google and here on stack overflow.

So if what I am doing is stupid or doesn't sound correct I'm sorry.

Problem:
We use a software that utilizes asp to bring content together for our webpages since we have over 1000 products this makes my life easier.
However, I am trying to edit the source that generates our metatags and cannot get the IF statements to work. see below:

```
If (pcStrPageName = "living-in-a-printers-paradise.asp") Then

        Response.Write "<title itemprop=""name"">"""Living in a Printer's Paradise""" </title>" & vbcrlf & _ 
        "<META NAME=""description"" CONTENT="""The Wide-Format Printing Industry isn't always the easiest nor enjoyable industry to write or read about and we have decided to write for you, the reader.""" />" & vbcrlf & _ 
        "<META NAME=""Keywords"" CONTENT="""Wide Format Printers, Digital Media Warehouse Blog, Digital Media Warehouse, Large Format Printers, Wide Format Printing, Large Format Printing, Printer, Printing, Printer Blog, Printing Blog, Wide Format Printing Blog, Wide Format Printer Blog""" />" & vbcrlf & _ 
        "<META NAME=""Robots"" CONTENT=""index,follow"" />" & vbcrlf & _
        "<META NAME=""Revisit-after"" CONTENT=""30"" />" & vbcrlf
Else


        '// START - Write Meta Tags
            if trim(Title)<>"" then
                Response.Write "<TITLE itemprop=""name"">" & Title & "</TITLE>" & vbcrlf
            end if
            if trim(mtDescription)<>"" then
                Response.Write "<META NAME=""description"" CONTENT=""" & mtDescription & """ />" & vbcrlf
            end if
            if trim(Keywords)<>"" then
                Response.Write "<META NAME=""Keywords"" CONTENT=""" & Keywords & """ />" & vbcrlf
            end if

            '// No Follow on Search, Message pages, ViewCart page, Checkout pages, but Follow all others...
            If (pcStrPageName = "search.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "msg.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "msgb.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "checkout.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "onepagecheckout.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "viewcart.asp") OR (pcStrPageName = "showsearchresults.asp") OR (sScriptName = "viewprd.asp") Then
                Response.Write "<META NAME=""Robots"" CONTENT=""noindex,nofollow"" />" & vbcrlf & _ 
                                "<META NAME=""Revisit-after"" CONTENT=""30"" />" & vbcrlf
            Else
                Response.Write "<META NAME=""Robots"" CONTENT=""index,follow"" />" & vbcrlf & _
                                "<META NAME=""Revisit-after"" CONTENT=""30"" />" & vbcrlf
            End If

            '// Add Canonical URL
            if pcStrCanonicalURL<>"" then
                'if UCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS"))="ON" then
                '   pcStrCanonicalURL=replace(pcStrCanonicalURL,"http://","https://")
                'end if
                Response.Write "<link rel=""canonical"" href=""" & pcStrCanonicalURL & """ />" & vbcrlf
            end if
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I had 3 """ instead of 2 "" by changing those the problem goes away. Sorry for wasting your time!! –